# Determine source for <script> tag using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I need to grab a php variable to determine what is in the "src" of a `<script>`.

Example:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="<?php echo $providerurl; ?>" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: For this example, what are you expecting to get back?  Are you expecting this to run on the server, before PHP has executed, or do you want this after it's been served to the client?

Comment: Nothing about this make sense, you'll have to elaborate. What exactly are you trying to output, the URL of a local file? Or are you trying to use PHP to get the `src` attribute of a `<script>` tag that exists on the page?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do... the code you pasted seem fine

Comment: You're doing this correctly if I understand you right - the PHP will execute on the server-side and echo the SRC into the `<script>` tag before it gets run.

Comment: `language="JavaScript"` is completely redundant and will not validate. A script tag needs `type="text/javascript"`, an optional `src="whatever"` and no other attributes.

Comment: @DaveRandom  in HTML5 it doesn't need any attributes other than "src" - "type" is "text/javascript" by default and the "type" attribute is optional.

Comment: @Pointy Do you have a reference for that? [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script) are being abnormally ambiguous on the subject when it comes to versions.

Comment: You need to use PHP to grab a PHP variable's value? Huh? `$src = $providerurl` already...

Comment: @DaveRandom https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script says "If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript." and in their [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Script#Examples) they explicitly omit the `src` attribute for HTML5.

Comment: @meagar I know, it's just the lack of an explicit statement that says "since HTML5, the type attribute is optional" - the way the description is worded it almost suggests that this may be true of HTML4.01 or even prior to that. I *think* I'm prepared to just take your word for it one this one though ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom [here's the section of the HTML5 "for developers" page](http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html)

Comment: @DaveRandom the example is pretty explicitly. It shows the same tag in HTML4 and HTML5 and the only difference is they omit the `src`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **grab** the src from a script tag, you can use DOMDocument.

```
$html = '<script language="JavaScript" src="some/url.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("script");
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  $attributes = $node->attributes;
  foreach ( $attributes as $attr )
  {
    if ( $attr->name == "src" ) $grabbed_src = $attr->value;
  }
}
```